# How do I create a bottom cut half oval shaped button in Android?

Tags: android, xml, button, shapes

I'm trying to create a half oval shaped button, which was easy in the mockup but I found it to be quite difficult doing in the XML file. Also I would like the ripple effect to be constrained only to the oval.
There may be a way to cut an oval in the shape XML file that I am not aware of.

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: bottom half oval button]

But the closest I got is:

[image: What i got so far]

Using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#8C9AEE"/>
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="60dp"/>
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="140dp"
        android:topRightRadius="140dp"/>
</shape>
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Non of the options I saw achieved the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following code**

> custom_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#8C9AEE" />
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="60dp" />

</shape>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout             
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#8C9AEE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Hope you helpful!